# Intersecting a list of lists of maps overriding equality

Tags: clojure

I have a list of lists of maps:

```
(( {:id 1 :temp 1} {:id 2} ) 
 ( {:id 1 :temp 2} )
 ( {:id 1 :temp 3} {:id 2} ))
```

I want to get ids which are at intersection of these 3 sets only by `:id` key. So my result here will be `1`

I came up with this solution but it's hurting my eyes:

```
(def coll '(( {:id 1 :temp 1} {:id 2} )
            ( {:id 1 :temp 2} )
            ( {:id 1 :temp 3} {:id 2} )))

(apply clojure.set/intersection 
       (map set (map (fn [m] 
                         (map #(select-keys % '(:id)) m)) coll)))
```

returns

```
#{{:id 1}}
```

which is Ok, but any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with getting `#{1}` (as you mention initially) instead of `#{{:id 1}}`, then it can be slightly improved:

```
(apply set/intersection (map (fn [c] (into #{} (map :id c))) coll))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(require '[clojure.set :refer [intersection]])
```

The select keys I guess you don't need, since you are only interested in the id. `(map :id  m)` does the job for the inner-most map. By this you are getting rid of a function shorthand. You can use it in the next map:

```
(map #(map :id  %) coll)
;; ((1 2) (1) (1 2))
```

The third map you introduce is not necessary. it can be merged in the above piece of code:

```
(map (comp set #(map :id  %)) coll)
```

or:

```
(map #(set (map :id %)) coll)
```

both evaluating to: `(#{1 2} #{1} #{1 2})`

This is still pretty nested. Threading macros don't help here. But you can use a very powerful list comprehension macro called `for`:

```
(for [row coll]
  (set (map :id row)))
```

This gives you the advantage of naming list items (rows) but keeping it concise at the same time.

So finally:

```
(apply intersection (for [row coll]
                      (set (map :id row))))
;; #{1}
```

Comment: Thank you Anton, I went with the other answer just because I had choose one :)